# Custom Post Type Creating 404s?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I  have a category named "movies" so I have have `site.com/movies/content-goes-here` but I'm not sure if the custom post type is clashing with the category, or if somethign is just not done correctly.

Here is the custom post type:

```
    function movie_post_type() {
    register_post_type('movies', array(
    'labels' => array(
    'name' => 'Movie Posts',
    'singular_name' => 'Movie',
    'add_new' => 'Add New',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit ',
    'new_item' => 'New movie post',
    'view_item' => 'View movie post',
    'search_items' => 'Search movie posts',
    'not_found' => 'No movie posts found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No movie posts found in Trash'
    ),
    'public' => true,

    'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag')
    ));
    }


 add_action('init', 'movie_post_type');
```

Did I do anything incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure but it sounds like you need to go to `Settings > Permalinks` and click on `Save Changes` to clear your rewrite cache.